# ServiceStack - Service consuming others services

Tags: servicestack

I've a question about how iI should consume services in ServiceStack from others services.

I've response DTOs for all my requests, witch implements `IReturn` interface. With a client like `JsonServiceClient`, when I make the requests, it returns the object response with the type implemented in `IReturn`, great!

Now that I'm re-factoring a project writing plugins for the services to use in future projects, when I inject a service in another service and make a request, it returns the object type, so I have to cast it to `HttpResult`, then cast the object response to the DTO type.

In most of my service method signatures, I've object as return type and then I return an `HttpResult` with the response. For example:

```
public object Get(Request request)
{
    return new HttpResult(responseObj);

}
```

Do I have any alternative, besides consume the services from a client?

I've a service and DTOs just for views, which consume others services from plugins. That's why I need to get the response DTO properly (the services for views act like controllers).

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use the return type object instead of the return type DTO? `public MyResponse Get(MyRequest request)...`

Comment: In fact there wasn't! I've opened this bounty for no reason, since it was an fail in my app architecture. The MyRequest in the question is an request at controllers level (services that consume others services), that's why i needed to return object or response status (for httpstatuscode and etc) :)

Comment: Could you please provide more info on how are you doing it at the moment?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid have not understood  your question and I am out of subject,

but I would use the same response object, changing only the request.

in Service Model

```
                public class TestRequest : IReturn<TestResponse>
                {
                 public int Id { get; set; }
                 public string name { get; set; }    
                }
                public class LowLevelRequest : IReturn<TestResponse>
                {
                 public int Id { get; set; }
                 public string name { get; set; } 
                 public string permissions { get; set; }      
                }

                public class TestResponse
                {
                  public bool success { get; set; }
                  public string message { get; set; }
                }
```

in Routing table

```
                    Routes
                      .Add<TestRequest>("/TestAPI/{Id}", "POST,GET, OPTIONS")
                      .Add<LowLevelRequest>("/InternalAPI/{Id}", "POST,GET, OPTIONS");
```

in Services

```
                  public TestResponse Post(TestRequest request)
                  {      JsonServiceClient client=new JsonServiceClient();
                         LowLevelRequest  lowrequest=new LowLevelRequest() { Id=request.Id, name=request.name, permissions="RW"  }                                                           
                        return  client.Post<TestResponse>(lowrequest);
                   }

                  public TestResponse Post( LowLevelRequest request)
                  {      ....
                         return new TestResponse() { success=true, message="done" };
                  }
```